# Every metric space contains a discrete, coarsely dense subset

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm wondering on how to prove the following:

Let $(X,d) $ be a metric space. We say that a subset $ A \subset X $ is coarsely dense iff $ \exists_{C > 0} \forall_{x \in X} \exists_{a \in A} d(x,a) < C$. Every metric space contains a discrete coarsely dense subset.

I found this statement in this paper:
http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~erik/papers/cat0-A.pdf and it says there that it's a straightforward application of Zorn's lemma.

I guess that by *discrete* we mean a space in which singletons are open (this should be equivalent to the condition: all balls are finite. Am I making sense?)

Then we look at the family $ \{D \subset X~ | ~  D \text{ is discrete}\} $. It doesn't make much sense, since I don't know how every chain could be bounded in this family.

What should I use? Which family should I consider?

I'd appreciate some help

Comment: To be discrete does not mean that all balls are finite. For a counterexample, take the metric on an infinite set such that each nonzero distance is equal to $1$. Instead, to be discrete means each point is an open set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different family will work. Pick a number $\epsilon > 0$. Use the family of all sets $D$ such that for all $x \ne y \in D$ we have $d(x,y) > \epsilon$. Every chain will be bounded, because the union of each chain still satisfies the property that for all $x,y$ in the union we have $d(x,y) > \epsilon$. A maximal set $D$ will have the property that each $x \in X$ has distance $\le \epsilon$ from some point in $D$, or else $D \cup \{x\}$ violates maximality of $D$.